# Any tips on developing an RTS unit movement collision?

Tags: collision-detection, algorithm, path-finding, rts, strategy

so I am developing an RTS and I am a little stuck at this. I am not talking about pathfinding algorithms like A*. The problem is moving units in bulk and their collision along the way. Can anyone give me some pointers or tips on how to start working on this. Older RTSs have a lot of problems in this. Warcraft 3 for example. When playing it now after some SC2 it is excruciating when units collide and block each others path and so on. I really want to avoid that. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a good answer but the a general direction I would lead you in would be using flocking / boids if you want to research that.

Comment: that is crowd movement or swarming, there is a set of papers on that [here](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/)

Comment: Duplicates: [Pathfinding for a lot of units, mostly random movement](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28133/)  [Pathfiding for groups of agents](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48884/pathfiding-for-groups-of-agents?rq=1) Answers that'll help [How does Flow Field pathfinding work?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/387/) [How do I implement group formations in a 3D RTS?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28146/)